# How do I use xsl format-number func. on an attribute?

Tags: xslt

I have a value I am parsing from an xml file that I need to stick into my table. I have the number displaying, but need to have it as "#,###.0" instead of just the integer. I got the number using:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="amount/@pricePerUnit"/></td>
```

The price per unit is, let's say, 2. As I said, I need "2.0".

I have tried

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="amount/@format-number(pricePerUnit,'#,###.0')"/></td>
```

and

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="amount/format-number(@pricePerUnit,'#,###.0')"/></td>
```

but neither works.  Have looked around with the googles, but can't seem to find the correct syntax.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Would it help if you put the xpath inside the function, rather than the other way around?  Like so:  `format-number(amount/@pricePerUnit, '#,###.0')`.  Maybe worth a shot...

Comment: Yep. Thanks Xavier.  Sucks to be new, sometimes.  Soon as I saw your answer, I thought, "Damn it, that's so obvious".  Thanks!  Put that answer up and I'll vote it as favorite.

Comment: Just did that.  And no worries - that's what we're here for.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your xpath inside the function, as the first argument:

```
format-number(amount/@pricePerUnit, '#,###.0')
```

That'll find the value of your attribute node, pass it into the format-number() function, and give you back the return value.